# Max Heapify Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, heap, heapsort

I am bit confused. If I have an array I have to build a tree. To compare the childern I have to know how large my array is in this case its N = 6 so I have to divide it by 2 so I get 3. That means I have to start from index 3 to compare with the parent node. If the child is greater than the parent node then I have to swap it otherwise I don't have to. Then I go to index 2 and compare with the parent if the children is greater than the parent node then I have to swap it. Then index 1 I have to compare with the children and swap it if needed. So I have created a Max heap. *But know I don't get it but why do I have to exchange A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfF6O.jpg) with A[6] then A[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfF6O.jpg) with A[5]. Finally I dont get the Max heap I get the Min Heap? What does Heapify mean?*

Thanks alot I appreciate every answer!

One of my exercise is **Illustrate the steps of Heapsort by filling in the arrays and the tree representations**

[image]

Comment: So when I doing Max or Min Heapify I have to exchange the first and the last node and then in every iteration I have to compare A[i] with the other nodes until I reach A[i-1]?

Comment: After exchanging A[1] and A[6] -> why can I just compare the left side 1 and 4 and swap it but not 3 and 7? Also the case and also after exchaning A[1] with A[5] why can I only swap 4 and 2 but not 3 and 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many implementations of a heap data structure, but one is talking about a specific [implicit binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation). [Heap-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) is done in-place, so it uses this design. Binary heaps require a [compete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), so it can be represented as an implicit structure built out of the array: for every `A[n]` in zero-based array,

- `A[0]` is the root; if `n != 0`, `A[floor((n-1)/2)]` is the parent;
- if `2n+1` is in the range of the the array, then `A[2n+1]` is the left child, or else it is a leaf node;
- if `2n+2` is in the range of the array, then `A[2n+2]` is the right child.

Say one's array is, `[10,14,19,21,23,31]`, is represented implicitly by the homomorphism, using the above rules, as,

[image: The rules applied to [10,14,19,21,23,31].]

This is not following the max-heap invariants, so one must `heapify`, probably using [Floyd's heap construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Floyd's_heap_construction) which uses `sift down` and runs in `O(n)`. Now you have a heap and a sorted array of no length, `([31,23,19,21,14,10],[])`, (this is all implicit, since the heap takes no extra memory, it's just an array in memory.) The visualisation of the heap at this stage,

[image: The heap [31,23,19,21,14,10].]

We pop off the maximum element of the heap and use `sift up` to restore the heap shape. Now the heap is one smaller and we've taken the maximum element and stored unshifted it into our array, `([23,21,19,10,14],[31])`,

[image: The heap [23,21,19,10,14].]

repeat, `([21,14,19,10],[23,31])`,

[image: The heap [21,14,19,10].]

`([19,14,10],[21,23,31])`,

[image: The heap [19,14,10].]

`([14,10],[19,21,23,31])`,

[image: The heap [14,10]]

`([10],[14,19,21,23,31])`,

[image: The heap [10].]

The heap size is one, so one's final sorted array is `[10,14,19,21,23,31]`. If one used a min-heap and the same algorithm, then the array would be sorted the other way.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Heap sort is a two phase process. In the first phase, you turn the array in a heap with the maximum value at the top A[1].  This is the first transition circled in red. After this phase, the heap is in the array from index 1 to 6, and the biggest value is at index 1 in A[1].

In the second phase we sort the values. This is a multistep process where we extract the biggest value from the heap and put it in place in the sorted array.

The heap is on the left side of the array and will shrink toward the left. The sorted array is on the right of the array and grows to the left.

At each step we swap the top of the heap A[1] that contains the biggest value of the heap, with the last value of the heap. The sorted array has then grown one position to the left. Since the value that has been put in A[1] is not the biggest, we have to restore the heap. This operation called max-heapify. After this process, A[1] contains the biggest value in the heap whose size has been reduced by one element.

By repeatedly extracting the biggest value left in the heap, we can sort the values in the array.

The drawing of the binary tree is very confusing. It's size should shrink at each step because the size of the heap shrinks.

Comment: Thanks chmike for the explanation. I do understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

See this image for explanation

[image: 1]